# EntityFramework and Expressions translation

Tags: entity-framework, linq-expressions

I have a entity class `Foo` I've made partial containing the following code

```
private readonly static Expression<Func<Foo, int>> MyKeyExpression = (x) => x.Key;

public int MyKey
{
   get { return MyKeyExpression.Compile()(this); }
}
```

The above works as in I can use `MyKey` in EntityFrameworks linq queries.

Why don't the following work?

```
private readonly static Expression<Func<Foo, int>> MyKeyExpression = (x) => x.Key;

// Set in the constructor with
// _myKeyDelegate = MyKeyExpression.Compile();
private readonly Func<Foo,int> _myKeyDelegate;

public int MyKey
{
   get { return _myKeyDelegate(this); }
}
```

I understand the difference between a delegate and an expression(or maybe i don't?) but is confused how EntityFramework is able to interpret the property differently since `MyKeyExpression.Compile()` returns just that delegate which is then invoked returning an int. Perhaps its my lack of understanding of how the compiler actually handles C# Properties?

Example of usage where first example works but second examples throw a exception about not being able to translate it to SQL.:

```
dbContext.Foo.Delete(x => x.MyKey == 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you don't fully understand difference between delegates and expressions.

Delegate is a reference to code compiled into IL. Only thing you can with it is execute it within .net CLR.

Expression object is a expression represented as tree, (you can think of [AST](http://Abstract_syntax_tree)). You can compile it to IL (Compile method) or you can inspect it and generate code for other execution environment, for example into SQL (that's what EF does).

When C# compiler compiles code, first it builds syntax tree and then compiles it. Basically expression is result of first part without second, so you could use SQL translator to compile it to SQL. Or you can write you own and translate it to anything else.

Comment: I understand all that, I've used expressions before for exactly that. And it would make sense if `MyKey` returned `Expression<Func<Foo,int>>` vs `Func<Foo,int>`, the first it could translate to SQL but the second is simply code returning an int. If i reflect over `public int MyProperty { get{ return MyExpression.Compile()(this);}}` how will i be able to translate that to SQL, won't i just see property returning a int. The actual translateable code is in `MyExpression` is entity framework able to decompile the property and find `MyExpression` or how do that work?

Comment: `MyExpression.Compile()(this)` is the same as `_myKeyDelegate(this)`, both is just int. `MyExpression` vs `_myKeyDelegate` is what is important.

Comment: Im a idiot and it turned out my mistake was due to overloaded extension methods where one returned a IEnumeable and the other a IQueryable taking a Func and Expression respectively. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange what you are saying...
EF ignores the content of the getter and the setter of a mapped property (MyKey).

The query should be generated with a WHERE clause based on MyKey independent of what getter does.

How did you map the MyKey property? There is the setter missing so EF does not generate a field on the DB table and does not map it automatically.

Comment: `MyKey` is not mapped. I've created it in a partial class of the entity class `Foo`. `MyKey` do not exist in the database, `Key` exists. Basicly Im trying to map `Key` to `MyKey` so i can use `MyKey` in Linq expressions with entity framework.

Comment: If MyKey is not mapped there is no way for EF to generate a query on MyKey. If is mapped EF does not mind in what you insert in MyKey getter and setter. Also, if you use a function in a query, EF (the EF Provider to be more precise) need to know how to translate the function. I don't know what do you need to do, add a piece of an expression tree dynamically?

Comment: Instead of running a query write this var myQuery = dbContext.Foo.Where(x => x.MyKey == 5) and inspect myQuery (you can see the generated query if there is one).

Comment: I've use the following code dbContext.Foo.Max(x => x.MyKey) it just returns the maximum `Key` in the database just like expected. But if i change the code in `Foo` to my second example of `return _myKeyDelegate(this); ` it fails. But `return MyKeyExpression.Compile()(this);` works.